# Remove UISearchBar's Inner Shadow

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

How can I remove the UISearchBar's inner shadow?

I've tried `[[searchBar layer]setShadowOpacity:0]` but that didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 4):

1. Create a background image that has the appearance you want. For example,
   [click here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B9Ri89qqS5wiX2g3WTdfck1Ebjg?usp=sharing) to view the two stretchable images with end caps that I used.
2. Use the following api:

   ```
   [self.searchBar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search_field.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   ```

Comment: This makes the search bar rectangular in shape :(

Comment: Thank you so much, a brilliant solution!! Thanks also for creating those images, can you do the same for text fields - PLEASE :)

Answer (score 3):

```
    UITextField *textField = nil;

    for( UIView *subview in searchBar.subviews )
    { 
       if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            textField = (UITextField *)subview;
            textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
            textField.layer.borderWidth = 1.f;
            textField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
            textField.layer.cornerRadius = 14.0f;
            textField.background = nil;
            textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }
    }
```

Use this code could remove the UISearchBar's Inner Shadow.try it.

Answer (score 2):

```
    for( UIView *subview in searchBar.subviews )
    {
        if( [subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString( @"UISearchBarBackground" )] )
        {
            //   you can set the textField backgroundColor clearColor like below.
            //  [subview setAlpha:0.0f];
            //  break;


            //   or you can set textField backgroundColor solid color like below
            UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:subview.bounds];
            aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            [subview addSubview:aView];
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The first commented out code block doesn't do anything and the second one just colors the area behind the textfield. I changed UISearchBarBackground to UITextField and setting the shadow opacity on that layer doesn't seem to do anything either.

Comment: @AaronNg you mean textField`s shadow ? if you mean textField`s shadow , I think you need use KVC to change the shadowOffset of the shadow color , you can change [subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString( @"UISearchBarBackground" )] to [subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] to find the textField , and then change the shadow , but I don`t know the key name.